# Im having some major (possibly minor lol) issues in flutterflow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I am in the middle of developing an app in flutterflow and am running into an error i never have ran into before. Came with one of the recent updates i'm assuming.

When I go to pass a page parameter on a page associated with the NavBar it gives me the error "Cannot use page with required page parameters without default values on the nav bar.". It persists with parameters "DocumentReference" and "Document". Im not sure as to what value(s) it's referring to?

[Everything here has a default of 0 if not a number. Changing the background color does nothing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTFgk.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.